# API can't validate hmac + base64 when generated in a function

Tags: php, hash, hmac

I'm trying to use a function to generate the hmac hash enconded in base64. However, the endpoint can't validate that message.

When I generate the hmac hash enconded in base64 outside of a function, it works fine. The endpoint validates the message.

This is what I'm doing when using a function (this is how I need and can't make it work):

```
function genNonce() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    $nonce = (int)((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
    return $nonce;
}

function genMsg($nonce) {
    $signature = strtoupper(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $nonce . $key, $secret, true)));
    return $signature;
}

$nonce = genNonce();
$signature = genMsg($nonce);

$auth = Array();
    $auth[] = "key: " . $key;
    $auth[] = "nonce: " . $nonce;
    $auth[] = "signature: " . $signature;

...execute curl...
```

I tried to debug dumping the vars when executing the function and right before executing curl, they match. So it seems that it's generating the information and sending it through.

And this is what I'm doing when not using a function (this is how it's working):

```
list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
$nonce = (int)((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
$signature = strtoupper(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $nonce . $key, $secret, true)));

$auth = Array();
    $auth[] = "key: " . $key;
    $auth[] = "nonce: " . $nonce;
    $auth[] = "signature: " . $signature;

...execute curl...
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Why am I getting different results? Is it an issue of the endpoint API?

Edit: The error that the API is returning is "INVALID_SIGNATURE". I also tried to take the same values and make a request through SoapUI. I get the same error when using the first case (functions) and it works fine when using the second case (outside functions). So, why is it generating wrong hashes when using a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.

I was not passing $key and $secret to genMsg().

```
function genNonce() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    $nonce = (int)((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
    return $nonce;
}

function genMsg($nonce, $key, $secret) {
    $signature = strtoupper(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $nonce . $key, $secret, true)));
    return $signature;
}

$nonce = genNonce();
$signature = genMsg($nonce, $key, $secret);
```